# How to enable the effect of "using" for a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, using

The page I'm developing's had the syntax as follows.

```
@model List<Group>
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
```

All of the sudden, because of a change that I'm not aware of (and can't retrace), VS starts demanding that I specify a full qualifier like this.

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<Group>
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
```

When I do that, Resharper marks it as necessary (which it should be, according to the code from before). My guess is that I've unknowingly removed a using somewhere but I can't figure of where.

Since I'm using Razor and MVC, there's no code-behind and frankly speaking I wonder where the information about that the *List* came from before it broke. I mean, there's got to be an information about the full qualifier *System.Collections.Generic* somewhere. Where is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework will use namespaces defined in the Web.config found in the Views folder (**not** the application Web.config).  The syntax looks like:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

You can also use a namespace in a single file using the syntax:

`using System.Collections.Generic`